# How can I resolve this error in databinding - android studio

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have been trying to experiment with data binding and so far I have encountered a problem and I don't know how to fix it

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\evere\AndroidStudioProjects\Santiago1\app\build.gradle' line: 9
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not set unknown property 'enabled' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

  plugins {
  id 'com.android.application'
  }

android {

```
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
}
compileSdkVersion 30

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.santiagofinals"
    minSdkVersion 25
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}


dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

}

**Additional errors**
C:\Users\evere\AndroidStudioProjects\santiagofinals\app\src\main\java\com\example\santiagofinals\Sjrvca.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
import com.example.santiagofinals.databinding.EmployeeListItemBinding;
^
symbol:   class EmployeeListItemBinding
location: package com.example.santiagofinals.databinding

Comment: It seems that you have some problems in the gradle file. Can you provide your gradle file contents?

Comment: @RazvanS. Provided the contents of build.gradle(:app)

Comment: You need to enable data binding like you can see here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start. After you do that if you still have issues you can checkout this https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding